# UIImageview+AFNetworking fade in, also when the image is cached

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, afnetworking

I want achieve the fade in effect with the the `UIImageView+AFNetworking` categories, i have found this amazing fade in code:

https://gist.github.com/manmal/5038010

and works very very well, but when the image is already cached there is no fade in like you can see at line `13` of the `.m` file, it's possible to achieve the fade in also when the image is cached?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this very easily by just getting rid of the `if` statement that checks for this.

Change this:

```
[self setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    if (!request) // image was cached
        [weakSelf setImage:image];
    else
        [UIView transitionWithView:weakSelf duration:duration options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
            [weakSelf setImage:image];
    } completion:nil];
} failure:nil];
```

into this:

```
[self setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    [UIView transitionWithView:weakSelf duration:duration options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
            [weakSelf setImage:image];
    } completion:nil];
} failure:nil];
```

Comment: thanks, it's the first attempt i have made, but the problem is that removing that "if" when the uicollectionview scroll the cell take image of other cell...

Comment: just set the image to nil before you call this function

Comment: I think the image is cached if the `response` is nil, not the `request`.